# LIBGDX и Android Project

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Здравствуйте. Что бы обратиться из сцены в андроид классы - я использовал интерфейсы. Но, как обратится из android класса к сцене?
Например, при нажатии кнопки на сцене происходит запрос на метод в Android проекте, он что-либо подсчитывает и мне после этого нужно открыть например дрпугую сцену, как это возможно?

Насчет return ответы не давайте, это работает, но мне нужно открыть сцену именно из android проекта.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать следующую систему событий. Есть специальный объект с методом `Dispatch`, который в дальнейшем мы будем переопределять:

```
public class EventObject implements EventObject {
    @Override
    public void Dispatch(Object data) {

    }
}
```

Добавим класс, реализующий систему регистрации таких объектов, связанных с вызывающими их событиями `EventType`:

```
public abstract class AbstractStream {

    public enum EventType {};

    private ListMultimap<Object, EventObject> listeners = ArrayListMultimap.create();

    public void addListener(EventObject listener, Object eventType){
        listeners.put(eventType, listener);
    }

    public void removeListener(EventObject listener, Object eventType){
        listeners.remove(eventType, listener);
    }

    public void callEvent(Object eventType, Object data) {
        for (EventObject hl : listeners.get(eventType)) hl.Dispatch(data);
    }
}


public class RealStream extends AbstractStream {

    public enum EventType {
        SomethingHappens
    }
}
```

Теперь достаточно подписаться на событие `SomethingHappened` в классе, в котором нужно вызвать метод:

```
public class TestClass implements MyActivatedController {

    private EventObject dispatchObject;

    public TestClass() {
        dispatchObject = new EventObject() {
            @Override
            public void Dispatch(Object data) {
                TestMethod(data);
            }
        };
    }

    public void Activate() {
        SomethingStatic.RealStream.addListener(dispatchObject, RealStream.EventType.SomethingHappens);
    }

    public void Deactivate() {
        SomethingStatic.RealStream.removeListener(dispatchObject, RealStream.EventType.SomethingHappens);
    }

    public void TestMethod(Object data) {
        Gdx.app.log("TestMethod", (String)data));
    }
}
```

Остается только вызвать метод `callEvent`

```
SomethingStatic.RealStream.callEvent(
SomethingStatic.RealStream.EventType.SomethingHappens, "Test data");
```

что приведет к вызову `TestMethod` с заданным нами параметром.